# Splitting data from one record is a specific column T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, split, substring, max

I'm working on a old legacy database that got imported into SQL Server 2012 from Oracle. I have the following table called `INSOrders` which includes a column called `OrderID` of type `varchar(8)`.

An example of the data inserted is:

```
A04-05  |  B81-02  |  C02-01
A01-01  |  B95-01  |  C99-05
A02-02  |  B06-07  |  C03-02
A98-06  |  B10-01  |  C17-01
A78-07  |  B02-03  |  C15-03
A79-01  |  B02-01  |  C78-06
```

First Letter = Ordertype, next 2 digit = Year - and last 2 digit = OrderNum within that Year.

So I split all the data into 3 column : (not stored , just presented)

```
select 
    orderid,
    substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid)) as ordtype,
    right(max(datepart(yyyy, '01/01/' + substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2))),2) as year,
    max(substring(orderid, patindex('%-[0-9]%', orderid) + 1, 2)) as ordnum
from 
    ins.insorders
where 
    orderid is not null
group by 
    substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid)), orderid
order by 
    ordtype
```

It is looking like this:

```
OrderID  |  OrderType  |  OrderYear  | OrderNum
---------+-------------+-------------+----------
A04-05   |  A          |  04         |  05
A01-01   |  A          |  01         |  01
B10-03   |  B          |  10         |  03
B95-01   |  B          |  95         |  01
etc....
```

But now I just want to select the Max for all of the `OrderType`: show only the max for letter A, Show the max for letter B, etc. What I mean Max, I mean from Letter A I need to show the latest year and the latest ordernumber. so if I have A04-01 and A04-02 Just show A04-02.

I need to modify my query were I can see the following:

```
OrderID  |  OrderType  |  OrderYear  | OrderNum
---------+-------------+-------------+----------
A04-05   |  A          |  04         |  05
B10-03   |  B          |  10         |  03
C17-01   |  C          |  17         |  01
```

Thank you, I will truly appreciate the help.

Comment: This is kind of weird, so I assume in `B10-03` `OrderYear` shows `10` instead of `95` because `10` is represented as `2010` and `95` is represented as `1995?`

Comment: Wouldn't this be as simple as using MAX(orderid) and removing orderid from the group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below. Using your original query as a cte and assigning row numbers to each group of order types based on order year and order number. Then get all row number 1's which should be the max for each order type.

This little bit `DATEPART(yyyy,('01/01/' + OrderYear))` will make sure we get the correct year so that 95 is 1995 and 10 is 2010 etc.

```
   ;WITH cte 
    AS (
    select orderid,
    substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid)) as ordtype,
    right(max(datepart(yyyy,'01/01/' + substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2))),2) as year,
    max(substring(orderid, patindex('%-[0-9]%', orderid) + 1, 2)) as ordnum
    from ins.insorders
    where orderid is not null
    group by substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid)), orderid
    )

SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 
        *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderType ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy,('01/01/' + OrderYear)) DESC, OrderNum DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM cte) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is represented poorly and I only have a way to "cheese" it, and we'll need to make a lot of assumptions:

```
with cte_example
as
( your query )
select OrderID
       ,OrderType
       ,OrderYear
       ,OrderNum
from
(select *, row_number() over(partition by OrderType order by OrderYear DESC) rn      
from cte_example
where OrderYear <= right(year(getdate()),2)) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Since you already have a query extracting the information I won't bother changing it. We wrap your query in a CTE, query from it and apply the `row_number` function to decide which`OrderType` has the most recent `OrderYear`, along with its `OrderNum` and `OrderID`

Now the tricky part is that the years are poorly represented (assuming my comment on your original post is true), then using any sort of aggregation for `OrderType` `B` will return `95` since it is numerically greatest.

We make the assumption that no order date will be greater than this current year, and anything greater is in the 90s, using this statement: `where OrderYear < right(year(getdate()),2)`. In other words get this year and the two right characters of it. First by retrieving `2017` from `getdate` and then `17` with the `RIGHT` function. I'm sure why you can see this is dangerous, because what if your latest date is 1999?

So by filtering them out, we can then see the latest year for each `OrderType`... hope this helps.

[Here](http://rextester.com/HLEN66954) is the rextester test I built around to play with your query in case you want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original query was almost exactly what you needed except you need to use MAX(OrderID) and not group by it.

```
declare @Something table
(
    orderid varchar(6)
)

insert @Something
(
    orderid
) values
('A04-05'), ('B81-02'), ('C02-01'),
('A01-01'), ('B95-01'), ('C99-05'),
('A02-02'), ('B06-07'), ('C03-02'),
('A98-06'), ('B10-01'), ('C17-01'),
('A78-07'), ('B02-03'), ('C15-03'),
('A79-01'), ('B02-01'), ('C78-06')

select max(orderid),
substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid)) as ordtype,
right(max(datepart(yyyy,'01/01/' + substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2))),2) as year,
max(substring(orderid, patindex('%-[0-9]%', orderid) + 1, 2)) as ordnum
from myTable
where orderid is not null
group by substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid))
order by ordtype
```